# Issue with a while-loop while executing it

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, while-loop

I have a program that implements a minigame with `swing`, and in the main class I have a loop which listens to a Boolean in the map of the game. The loop implemented with `while` does not execute an instruction if it is the only one and I don`t know why.

I tried putting some other instructions to check if loop goes on, and it worked fine, but when I put only the `if` that I want it does not work.

```
public class ejecutor extends JFrame{
boolean ejecutando = true;
    
    public ejecutor(){
        mapa mapa = new mapa(); //the map of my game
        setSize(665,690);
        add(mapa);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        while(ejecutando){ 
            if(mapa.todasComidas()){
            //wLabel();
            ejecutando=false;
            System.out.println("You finished!!");
            }
//If I put this println it works, if I only use the If, without any other instruction inside the while, it does not do anything at all
            System.out.println("............");
        }
    }
//I execute the constructor in the main...
```

Comment: Don't [block the event dispatch thread](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bswing%5d%20block%20event%20dispatch%20thread).

Comment: "//If I put this println it works" may suggests problem related to [Questions about thread+loop not working without print statement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269174)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default boolean variables of a Java Object in Java gets set to default value as `false`. Looking at your code `mapa.todasComidas()`, you never explicitly set the same.

Now in your while loop, you are checking whether `todasComidas` method returns you `true` which won't be the case and hence never resets the same i.e. execute the inner statements of if condition. Your outer statement does gets executed and prints on console as its not guarded by any if conditions.

Comment: But it does execute the `If` statement when I put the `println`, thanks for the explanation anyway, I think you may be right, and I will check the values of the boolean at all times to fix it.